# Is SwipeToRefresh layout is available in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, swiperefreshlayout

I need to use swipe to refresh layout in my xamarin forms app.
I know how to use pull to refresh.
But, I am not getting swipe to refresh layout control in xamarin forms.
How I can use swipe to refresh layout in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its available in XamarinForms.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
```

For this you need to follow MVVM pattern because RefreshCommand not event.
So RefreshCommand binding with your MVVM command and you can easily refresh your list.

Comment: Please review the question before you answer.

Comment: how is this relative to the swipe-to-refresh-layout?

Comment: Tell me reason why you need refresh layout, Layout is always static, and Data will come in List only. look at facebook, Linkedin or any other app Swipe to refresh can works only with List.